# Map all links according to the key / value dictionary in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

how to map all links according to the key / value dictionary.

example component:

```
const Error1 = () =>
<>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <p>test <a href="test1">link</a></p>
</>

const Error2 = () =>
<>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <div>test <p><a href="test2">link</a></p></div>
</>

const dictionary = {
 test1: "www.test1.com",
 test2: "www.test2.com"
}
```

// in this component he wants to give a target link

```
const RenameLink = ({ children }) => children
```

example:

```
<RenameLink><Error1/></RenameLink>
```

result:

```
<h1>test</h1>
<p>test <a href="www.test1.com">link</a></p>
```

Comment: What is the relationship that the dictionary has with the Error components? Is it the href?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, just href

Comment: What have you tried? What about using props? What about using React.Children.map?

Comment: I tried React.Children.map and React.cloneElement but I don't know where the href component will be nested.

Comment: It’s not a component. Why not pass in the href value as a prop?

Comment: the Error component can have multiple links

Comment: Fab, this is the sort of thing you need to be thinking about when making components. Props can be used to fill in data  for the error component. Or you could pass on the links as children and keep the error component free of that stuff.